# How to call TextInput onEndEditing when onBlur in React Native

Tags: react-native, events, textinput, onblur

In React Native, How to call TextInput `onEndEditing` callback when `onBlur` event is fired?

Comment: A little bit of more context would be desired. What do you want to achieve and what have you tried so far? Because from your question I really don't understand why would you want to do that... But with a bit more context, maybe it's something else that you need.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

with this code I can call onEndEditing callback when onBlur event is fired

```js
<TextInput
    ref={ input => { this.thisInput = input }}
    clearButtonMode={"always"}
    multiline = {false}
    numberOfLines = {1}
    maxLength = {16}
    onEndEditing={ event => {
        let value = (!!event.nativeEvent && !!event.nativeEvent.text ) ? event.nativeEvent.text : event;

        // some code
    }}
    onBlur={ blurEvent => {
        this.thisInput.props.onEndEditing( this.thisInput._lastNativeText );
    }}
/>
```